# Sum of 2^Pi mod 1000000007 for all i where Pi is sum of numbers in ith subset of a set X

Tags: algorithm, set

I am stuck on a problem in which I have to print **sum of 2<sup>P<sub>i</sub></sup> mod 1000000007** for all **i** where **P<sub>i</sub>**  is sum of numbers in **i**th **subset** of a **set X**.

**Length of set** can be upto **100000**.

**Value of element** in the range **[0,10<sup>12</sup>]**.

Here's the link of the Problem.
[Problem Statement](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/the-baudelaire-predicament/description/)

I could not find any approach other than Brute-Force which gives verdict TLE.

Here's the Problem Statement

Violet, Klaus and Sunny Baudelaire were given a task by Count Olaf to keep them busy while he acquires their fortune.He has given them N numbers and asked each of them to do the following:

He asked Sunny to make all possible subsets of the set of numbers.
Then he asked Klaus to find out the sum of the number in each subsets thus formed.
Finally he asked Violet to tell him the sum of 2<sup>P<sub>i</sub></sup> for all i where P<sub>i</sub> is sum of numbers in ith subset.

Since Count Olaf will be bored while listening to such a long number he's asked to give him the answer modulus 1000000007.

Can you help Baudelaires out of this predicament ?

**Input Format**

First line of input contains a single number N indicating the size of the set. The following line will containing N numbers that makes the set.

**Output Format**

Print the answer in a single line.

**Input Constraints**

1 ≤ N ≤ 105

0 ≤ a[i] ≤ 10<sup>12</sup>

Here's My Solution:

```
import itertools # importing module

#initializing the sum variable which will store final answer
t=0

#Input, number of elements in array
n=input()

#Input the array
arr=map(int,raw_input().split())

#Traverse all the possible combinations and update the sum variable 't'.
for i in xrange(len(arr)+1):
    for val in itertools.combinations(arr,i):
        x=sum(val)

        t=(t+2**x)%1000000007
#Print final answer
print t
```

Here's the working algorithm which passes all testcases in time limit but I don't get the logic behind it.

```
from sys import stdin
mod = 10**9 + 7
n = int(stdin.readline())
ans = 1
a = map(int,stdin.readline().split())
for i in a:
    j = pow(2,i,mod)
    ans = (ans*(j+1))%mod
print ans
```

@Moderators,admins etc.
Before putting this question on hold or marking off-Topic or closed....
Please comment the reason so that I can know the reason and if possible reword it or ask on any other StackExchange Site.
I first posted it on codegolf.stackexchange.com and people(moderators) there have suggested me to post it here as it comes under algorithm category.

You can read about it here.

[Programming Puzzles and Code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113586/sum-of-2pi-mod-1000000007-for-all-i-where-pi-is-sum-of-numbers-in-ith-subset-of)

Thank You

Comment: Also, show us what you already have.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/71886/755, http://stackoverflow.com/q/42952795/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @D.W.
okay, but there's no need of down voting a question which may be informative for everyone.I got my answer and have been already benefited from it.If you down vote it unnecessarily, then others might not be able to get the insight.Think before pressing that button.

Also, people on different sites (SO and CS) have different point of view.People here might be more concerned about coming up with solution,code etc. but CS people are more concerned about runtime analysis,math involved,proofs etc.
I by no means criticizing or insulting anyone, I am just telling general consensus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're given a set of numbers `X`, and are asked to compute `sum(2^sum(x for x in A) for A a subset of X)`.

Let `X` be the set `{x[0], x[1], ..., x[n]}`, and `S[i]` be the sum of the powers of 2 of the sums of the subsets of `x[0]...x[i]`. That is, `S[i] = sum(2^sum(x for x in A) for A a subset of x[0]...x[i]))`.

Subsets of `x[0]...x[i+1]` are either subsets of `x[0]...x[i]`, or subsets of `x[0]...x[i]` with `x[i+1]` added.

Then:

```
S[i+1] =   sum(2^sum(x for x in A) for A a subset of x[0]...x[i+1])
       =   sum(2^sum(x for x in A) for A a subset of x[0]...x[i])
         + sum(2^sum(x for x in A+{x[i+1]}) for A a subset of x[0]...x[i])
       =   sum(2^sum(x for x in A) for A a subset of x[0]...x[i])
         + sum(2^x[i+1] * 2^sum(x for x in A) for A a subset of x[0]...x[i])
       =   S[i]
         + 2^x[i+1] * S[i]
```

This gives us a linear-time method for computing the result:

```
A = [3, 3, 6, 1, 2]
m = 10**9 + 7
r = 1
for x in A:
    r = (r * (1 + pow(2, x, m))) % m
print r
```

Comment: Could you please tell me about the thought process, I mean how you reached to this solution.I was stuck for almost 2 months and still was not able to solve it.

Comment: I looked for a dynamic programming solution and followed the idea that 2^(a+b+c...) = 2^a * 2^b * 2^c...

Comment: See this answer by Rick Decker, another way to describe the same approach.I really thank you for the answer, It's just that I want you to look because I think it may help you in some way.
http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/71886/sum-of-2pi-mod-1000000007-for-all-i-where-pi-is-sum-of-numbers-in-ith-subset-of/71888